# What would be a good HATEOAS recommendation for returning report data?

Tags: hateoas, spring-hateoas

Spring HATEOAS - but also HATEOAS in general - is always about resources and and performing actions on them.

Like an Invoice resource which can be created (post), updated (put), retrieved (get) and deleted.

I wonder what the best practices for e.g. returning report data.
Like a daily, monthly, yearly revenue reports based on the invoices.

Would a Revenue or RevenueReport resource make sense? With just a get to return the required data?

Any recommendations?

Comment: Your report is a resource, and you GET it. With full HATEOAS you'll only get the top level of the report which will contain references for each detailed part, recursively. You'll also receive links for templates, styling, and javascript, for rendering and interaction.

Comment: `Would a Revenue or RevenueReport resource make sense? With just a get to return the required data?` Ofc. it makes sense. By choosing a link, try to use the link relation in your client and not the resource name/URL etc...